# Restoring extra user data with used permission android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS

Tags: android, accountmanager

i'm facing a problem when i'm trying to add an account explicitly in the `AccountManager`.

**The problem**

The bundle with user data is being saved in `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db`, but isn't being <del>saved</del> restored.

Code

```
// 1st step) Adding account with extra user data
String email = "betorcs@mail.com";

final Account a = new Account(email, getString(R.string.accountType));
final Bundle userData = new Bundle();
userData.putString("firstName", "Roberto");

final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
boolean saved = am.addAccountExplicitly(a, null, userData); // It's always returning true

// 2nd step) Restoring account and extra user data
Account[] as = am.getAccountsByType(getString(R.string.accountType)); // Assuming as.length == 1
String firstName = am.getUserData(as[0], "firstName"); // It's always null
```

Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

**BUT**

If i remove the permission `android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS` from manifest, everything works fine.

Does someone can see what it's wrong? Or why this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I replaced

```
// 1st step) Adding account with extra user data
String email = "betorcs@mail.com";

final Account a = new Account(email, getString(R.string.accountType));
final Bundle userData = new Bundle();
userData.putString("firstName", "Roberto");

final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
boolean saved = am.addAccountExplicitly(a, null, userData);
```

By

```
// 1st step) Adding account with extra user data
String email = "betorcs@mail.com";

final Account a = new Account(email, getString(R.string.accountType));
final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
boolean saved = am.addAccountExplicitly(a, null, null);
if (saved) {
     am.setUserData(a, "firstName", "Roberto");
}
```

Now it's working, i don't understand yet, but worked!

Tested in

- i9100
- i9300
- Nexus 4